# Laravel 4 many to many relationship not working, pivot table not found

Tags: model, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm currently having problems with a n:n relationship with Laravel 4, I'm having an error wiht pivot table which is quering on a table with with both components on singular name. I create a pivot table lands_objs and populate it:

**Models are:**

```
<?php
    class Obj extends Eloquent
    {
        protected $guarded = array();
        public static $rules = array();
        public $timestamps = false;
        public function land()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Land');
    }

<?php

    class Land extends Eloquent 
    {
        protected $guarded = array();
        public static $rules = array();
        public $timestamps = false;

        public function objs()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Obj');
        }
     }
```

Here is how I populate the pivot table following the standards. Of course lands, objs and lands_objs tables exist:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLandsObjsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('lands_objs', function($table) {
            $table->integer('land_id');
            $table->integer('obj_id');
        });
    }
}
```

With this structure I should be able to do thanks to Eloquent:

```
$land = Land::find(1);  //checked loads land fine
$objs = $land->objs; //--> HERE I TAKE THE ERROR
```

But I take the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'taylor.land_obj' doesn't exist
(SQL: select `objs`.*, `land_obj`.`land_id` as `pivot_land_id`, `land_obj`.`obj_id`
as `pivot_obj_id` from `objs` inner join `land_obj` on `objs`.`id` = `land_obj`.`obj_id`
where `land_obj`.`land_id` = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, ))
```

Shouldn't Laravel create the table lands_objs in spite of quering on land_obj? Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pivot table should be singular version of the table names it is linking, in alphabetical order so in your case:

land_obj rather than lands_objs

If you really don't want to use the default naming conventions you can also specify the table name as the 2nd param on the belongsToMany call in your models:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Obj', 'lands_objs');
```

and

```
return $this->belongsToMany('Land', 'lands_objs');
```

For more information see [docs here](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many)

Comment: Can you tell me what's the difference between using 2 **belongsTo** methods and the **hasManyThrough** method ? I don't understand, but using the hasManyTrough doesn't works for me...

Comment: Given the scenario an Author has many Posts and a Post has many Comments. You would have 2 belongs to methods typically (author to post and post to comment), however say you want to select all of the comments on all of the posts for a given author, then you'd use hasManyThrough because the comments aren't directly related to the Author but they are related to the Author via another model (post). Without hasManyThrough you'd have to select all the author's posts, then loop them getting all the comments, then do some sort of processing to get them into the format/order etc that you were after.