# Laravel 4 many to many relationship does not display the related data

Tags: many-to-many, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm working with the following models: Game, User and Player where Player extends User. In this case Game and Player have a relationship of N:N and User extends Confide. So code stands like:

**app/models/Game.php**

```
<?php

class Game extends Eloquent {

    protected $guarded = array();
    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function players(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Player');
    }
}
```

**app/models/User.php**

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser;

class User extends ConfideUser {
    protected $table = 'users';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    //Here go original Confide functions
}
```

**app/models/Player.php**

```
<?php

class Player extends User{
    public function games(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game');
    }
}
```

I've populated the pivot table called game_player. As player extends user, pivot table is like this:

**game_player**

```
id
game_id
user_id
```

But if I run this super simple example I have an error:

```
$game = Game::find($gameId);
$player = $game->players();  //Error in this line
```

**Error**

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::players()
```

I'm confused because I'm not having the [error about pivot table was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384926/laravel-4-many-to-many-relationship-not-working-pivot-table-not-found) so I could think relationship is created fine.

On the other hand if I var_dump games var I obtain:

**var_dump($game)**

```
object(Game)[181]
  protected 'table' => string 'games' (length=5)

  //more var info about DB

  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'guarded' =>
```

If relationship would be created fine... shouldn't relations var have any data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pointing out somethings that could solve the problem:

1. Your Game.php has the wrong table name.
2. When you get players, the line should be:

   $game = Game::with('players')->find($gameId);
   $player = $game->players;